# How to make org.kde.discover (Plasma Discover installed as FlatPak) to work with APT, Snap and FlatPak of the system?

Tags: 16.04, apt, snap, flatpak

I have installed FlatPak to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists kdeapps --from https://distribute.kde.org/kdeapps.flatpakrepo
```

and then installed Plasma Discover with

```
flatpak install kdeapps org.kde.discover
```

I can run it with

```
flatpak run org.kde.discover
```

or from *Applications→System→(Nightly) Discover*, but it does not show any installed applications

[image: Plasma Discover - Installed]

Settings tab is empty too:

[image: Plasma Discover - Settings]

What am I doing wrong?
How to make org.kde.discover (Plasma Discover installed as FlatPak) to work with APT, Snap and FlatPak of the system?

---

**Some background:** I want to stay on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and have GUI for FlatPak and Snap. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1026188/66509) was the first step.

**Notes:** I have tested this method on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Plasma Discover has the same behavior on it.

Comment: From much of what I've read, Plasma Discover, even in Kubuntu Bionic and Cosmic, is a bit dicey. So it is the focus of heavy development. Also, I'm guessing that Plasma Discover, the version using 5.13, is somewhat out of place on Ubuntu Xenial which will have older versions of APT, Snap, etc. I doubt whether Discover is backwards-compatible. Users of Cosmic just got updated to 5.13 a day before feature freeze. I can't help in any way, but would like to know why you're trying this on Xenial instead of in Cosmic?

Comment: This question is logic continuation of my other question - [I want to have GUI for FlatPak and Snap on 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1026188/66509). Thank you for comment, @DKBose , anyway!

Comment: IIRC, flatpaks are sandboxed. Installing discover as flatpak doesn't really make sense to me unless there is a way to un-sandbox it. As a side note: if it were possible, what would happen if you uninstall flatpak from discover running as a flatpak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want to achieve is not possible because flatpak applications are [sandboxed](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Sandbox).

I don't know any KDE developer, but judging by [this commit](https://cgit.kde.org/flatpak-kde-applications.git/commit/?id=4301a0fda68352bbe0663d0bf0ff13371c10f0a0) and [this blog post](https://pointieststick.com/2018/02/16/this-week-in-discover-and-kirigami-part-6/), they probably use the discover flatpak to test the UI. Discover is one prominent showcase of KDE's [Kirigami UI](https://www.kde.org/products/kirigami/). Using a flatpak for this purpose sounds reasonable to me.