# No flatpak updates in Ubuntu Software, but I see them in terminal

Tags: gnome-software, flatpak

I don't see the flatpak updates in Ubuntu Software, but after I input `flatpak update` in the terminal, lots of updates appear, why?
[image]

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? If you are running 18.04, then you can [switch to Plasma Discover](https://askubuntu.com/a/1068567/66509). In 16.04 there is [no GUI for FlatPaks](https://askubuntu.com/q/1026188/66509).

Comment: I'm using 18.10

Answer (score 0):

I found that my Software app stopped showing flatpak updates once I moved from the Ubuntu repository version of flatpak to the PPA version from ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak.

Maybe the integration is limited to the version provided by to official Ubuntu repositories?