# How to install CherryTree on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install [CherryTree](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/), my favorite note taking app on Ubuntu 20.04? I tried to install from github, but none of the dependencies are available on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: CherryTree is in the `Software` Store as a flatpak, and it works fine.

Comment: Here's how to install snap if `sudo apt install snapd` does not work: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593366/how-to-enable-snaps-support-on-linux-mint-20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now install cherrytree without snap:

https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/#downl

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:giuspen/ppa    # add the repo
sudo apt update                            # update package lists
sudo apt install cherrytree                # install
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned on the [download page of the developper](https://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/#downl), there are currently no .deb packages available for Ubuntu. The developper recommends to use the snap or flatpak packages.

By far the easiest way to install is by snap. You will find Cherrytree in the Snap store, or you can install it with the command

```
snap install cherrytree
```

If you want to access removable media, connect to the removable-media interface:

```
snap connect cherrytree:removable-media
```

It is also available as a flatpak. Both snap and flatpak are at the time of writing the latest stable version. Flatpak is by default not enabled on Ubuntu. You can enable it on your system with [a few commands](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/).

Manually installing on Ubuntu 20.04 is not recommended for typical users: it requires to install Python 2, which is now deprecated.

Comment: Snap didn't work for me: `Package snapd is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: CherryTree is in the `Software` Store as a flatpak, and it works fine.

Comment: Then your computer is malconfigured. I tested and it installs and runs fine. @heynnema only if you enabled flatpak on your system *and*, in 20.04, installed the regular software center instead of the snap store, *and* installed the gnome software plugin for flatpak .

Comment: @vanadium On my system, I have both `Software` store and `Snap Store`, and I can run snaps or flatpak apps. Not malconfigured. Configured to have more choices. The snap version of this app has some pretty bad reviews, while the flatpak reviews are pretty good. I'm running the flatpak version and it works fine :-)

Comment: @heynnema, the first part of my comment was not directed to you obviously ;) Comment of OP suggests that snap is not properly configured on his system.

Comment: @vanadium Ah, I misunderstood your comment. It's all good.

Answer (score 1):

First you need Python 2 pip which was strangely missing:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

More dependencies. Python gtk2-dev is available from this user's repository: https://askubuntu.com/a/1235347/951756

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/python2-stuff
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git libenchant1c2a
pip install pyenchant
sudo apt install python2 python-gtk2-dev p7zip-full python-dbus python-chardet
```

The easiest way to get python-gtksourceview is the older ubuntu debs: https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/python-gtksourceview2

After all that, Hopefully you should be able to run cherrytree directly from the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/giuspen/cherrytree    
cherrytree/cherrytree
```

Comment: Python 2 is now EOL. Thanks for using my PPA. Also I have e-mailed to giuspen [who packaged](https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=cherrytree&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=) CherryTree for previous Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @N0rbert  CherryTree is in the `Software` Store as a flatpak, and it works fine.

Comment: @heynnema, oh, right I see - [FlatPak and Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwIXN.png).

Comment: @N0rbert What is "App Outlet"?

Comment: @heynnema It is a [fresh project](https://app-outlet.github.io/). I have reviewed it [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1248843/66509)